# Updating box2d to newer version in Coco2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have been working with Cocos2d and the Box2d that comes bundled with it. I start my programs using the provided Box2d template. My problem is that I am trying to update to a newer version of box2d.

I assumed that eliminating the Box2D folder from my project and dragging the new version (2.2.1) would be enough, but after doing this I get a series of errors and broken links. I have tried to fix them but seems impossible. Is it that the bundled version has been modified to work better with Cocos2d?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have issues with the updating process and you can usually spend time ironing out the errors and warnings.

But in all honesty it's just better to do this:

1) Download latest version of Cocos2d with Box2d

2) Create a new project with the new templates

3) Transfer all your class files and resources into this new project

Comment: Yup because Box2D 2.2 changed a few API things (b2World constructor for example) and the DebugDraw class also needs to be updated.

Comment: still no solution. Downloading the latest version of cocos2d (v1.1) still doesn't pack the latest version of box2d (v2.1.2). I know I have to change my program but I am stuck in the first step which is to add the new box2d folders.